# Disable remote validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a model that uses remote validation. The model also acts as a parent class to a child class. How would i disable remote validation in the view for a particular field?
Model code

```
public user
{
  [Remote("Validateemail","User",etc)]
  public string Email {get; set;}
}

public edituser:user
{
  public int userid {get; set;}

  public edituser(int userid,string email)
  {
    userid=userid;
    Email=email;
  }
}
```

My aim is to remove the remove validation in the edituser class in the view.

Answer (score 0):

im assuming that you just need to display the email field and all the data in it as it is in editView because by defauflt a user cannot edit his/her email..
to so this you can just change the code in the view from 
`Html.EditorFor()` to `Html.DisplayFor()`

Comment: I am allowing the user to edit their email address. I just want to force the view not to apply remote validation thats implemented on the base class

Answer (score 0):

this is the perfect case for viewmodel. create a different viewmodel for edit (as a matter-effect view should not be linked directly to domain models in most of the cases)
or you can use IValidatableObject or fluentvalidation , or you can use DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider for manually attaching attribute condition based if it applies in your case.